# How to convert Bitmap to AndroidBitmap for push notifications in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, push-notification, notifications

I am trying to set up a large icon for push notification using `flutter_local_notifications` plugin and for the icon I want to use a network image. The code is as follows:

```
Bitmap bitmap = await Bitmap.fromProvider(NetworkImage("http://pudim.com.br/pudim.jpg")); 
var androidSpecifics = new AndroidNotificationDetails(
    notificationData['id'].toString(),
    'Crop2x Notifications',
    'Crop2x Channel Description',
    importance: Importance.max,
    priority: Priority.high,
    largeIcon: bitmap,
    ticker: 'ticker');
```

This code is giving an error because `bitmap` is of the type `Bitmap` and not of `AndroidBitmap` type, which the named argument `largeIcon` requires.

Comment: Can you share the packages for Bitmap and AndroidBitmap classes??

Comment: @DeePanShu Bitmap is from the 'Bitmap' package but don't know about AndroidBitmap.

Answer (score 1):

Explore [AndroidBitmap](https://github.com/MaikuB/flutter_local_notifications/blob/master/flutter_local_notifications/lib/src/platform_specifics/android/bitmap.dart) class.

Try to get image in format of `Uint8List` using `HTTP` connection:

```
Future<Uint8List> getImageBytes(String imageUrl) async{
     
     http.Response response = await http.get(
     Uri.parse('https://flutter.io/images/flutter-mark-square-100.png'));
     return response.bodyBytes; //Uint8List
}
```

and then after getting bodyBytes as future try to convert it into bitmap using `AndroidBitmap` class and `base64.encode()`:

```
getImageBytes("http://pudim.com.br/pudim.jpg").then((bodyBytes){

      AndroidBitmap androidBitmap = ByteArrayAndroidBitmap.fromBase64String(base64.encode(bodyBytes));

      var androidSpecifics = new AndroidNotificationDetails(
      notificationData['id'].toString(),
      'Crop2x Notifications',
      'Crop2x Channel Description',
      importance: Importance.max,
      priority: Priority.high,
      largeIcon: androidBitmap,
      ticker: 'ticker');
}};
```